# The decomposition and collection of back images to pieces 100x100 python

Tags: python, arrays, image, numpy

I have array of image, and I need to decompose it on pieces 100x100 and after manipulations with it collect back in original image. 
Problem: I can't collect pieces back, I have something like this,

[image]

but real image is 800x800

[image]

My code:

get img as array, remove third dimension

```
path_to_image = './la3.jpg'
image_array = plt.imread(path_to_image)
image_array = image_array[:, :, 0]
```

write in new array pieces 100x100 (work fine):

```
main2_array = np.zeros(10000,)
for row in tqdm_notebook(range(0,8)):

    for col in range(0,8):
        main2_array = np.vstack((main2_array, image_array[0 + (100*row):100 + (100*row) ,0 + (100*col):100 + (100*col)].flatten()))

main2_array = np.delete(main2_array, main2_array[0] , axis=0  )
```

collect pieces back(It's not working)

```
main_array = np.zeros(100,)

for p in tqdm_notebook(range(0,100)):
    for i in range(0,64):
        main_array = np.vstack((main_array, main2_array[0 + (10000*i) + (100*p): 100 + (10000*i) + (100*p)]))

main_array = np.delete(main_array, main_array[0] , axis=0  )
```

After collecting pieces I get

[image]

Comment: What is `tqdm_notebook`?

Comment: tqdm_notebook is tool to see status of process, such as line of download. https://tqdm.github.io/

Comment: Why do you create a 1-d zeros array, add rows to it then delete the original 1-d zeros array?

Comment: Your *collect the pieces* code produces a ValueError.  Please provide an [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fake image

```
x, y = 800,800
img_array = np.arange(x*y).reshape((x,y))
```

After your deconstruction, `main2_array.shape` is (64,10000); each row is a flattened 100x100 patch.  During deconstruction, you traversed the image *left-to-right*, *top-to-bottom* and slid each patch below the previous patch.

To reconstruct reverse the process:

```
main_array = np.zeros((x,y))
for n, patch in enumerate(main2_array):
    patch = patch.reshape(100,100)
    # eight patches per row
    row, col = divmod(n, 8)
    row_offset, col_offset = row*100, col*100
    row_slice = slice(row_offset, 100 + row_offset)
    col_slice = slice(col_offset, 100 + col_offset)
    #print(np.all(patch == image_array[row_slice,col_slice]))
    main_array[row_slice, col_slice] = patch


>>> np.all(main_array == img_array)
True
>>>
```

---

Or you could just reshape your way back to the original

```
>>> b = main2_array.reshape(8,8,100,100)
>>> b[0,1].shape    # row zero column 1? 
(100, 100)
>>> np.all(b[0,1] == a[0:100, 100:200])
True
>>> 
>>> c = np.swapaxes(b, 1,2)
>>> c.shape
(8, 100, 8, 100)
>>> np.all(c[0,:,1,:] == a[0:100, 100:200])    # row zero column 1? 
True
>>> d = c.reshape(800,800)
>>> np.all(d==img_array)
True
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

A bit late, but I believe the question deserves a more graphical answer.

You don't need slow loops, you can do it all with `numpy` reshaping and fancy indexing.

Let's start with a sample image

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  
import skimage.transform
import skimage.data

img = skimage.data.chelsea()
# crop from (300, 451, 3) to (300, 300, 3)
img = img[:,80:380,:]
# resize to (800, 800)
img = skimage.transform.resize(img, (800,800))
plt.imshow(img)
```

[image]

Decompose the image in `64` `100*100` tiles. New shape is `(8, 100, 8, 100, 3)` and you can address single images with `img[i, :, j, :, ...]`. No need to store them in a new array except maybe for easier readability.

```
img = img.reshape(8, 100, 8, 100, 3)
gs = mpl.gridspec.GridSpec(8,8)
for i in range(8):
    for j in range(8):
        ax = plt.subplot(gs[i,j])
        ax.imshow(img[i,:,j,:,...])
```

[image]

Now let's do some manipulation on the tiles.

Clear some random tile

```
cells = np.random.randint(8, size=(20,2))
img[cells[:,0],:,cells[:,1],...] = 1
```

Flip upside down and left to right

```
img = img[:,::-1,:,::-1,...]
```

Add black borders

```
img[:,:6,...] = 0
img[:,-6:,...] = 0
img[:,:,:,:6,...] = 0
img[:,:,:,-6:,...] = 0
```

And plot them

```
for i in range(8):
    for j in range(8):
        ax = plt.subplot(gs[i,j])
        ax.imshow(img[i,:,j,:,...])
```

[image]

Now to reconstruct you can just reshape to the original shape

```
img = img.reshape(800, 800, 3)
plt.imshow(img)
```

[image]